# How to use only one reference for forest plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, survival, forest-plot

I would like to generate a forest plot, but I have a problem with the wrong reference groups: The plot contains multiple reference elements because, I assume, the model is calculating the differences intra-groups. I would like to have instead only one reference as contrast (the treatment "rx" , in the example)

I have a plot like this:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(dplyr)

data(ovarian)
glimpse(ovarian)

ovarian <- ovarian %>% mutate(age_group = ifelse(age >=50, "old", "young"))
ovarian$age_group <- factor(ovarian$age_group)
str(ovarian)
# # Dichotomize age and change data labels
ovarian$rx <- factor(ovarian$rx,
                     levels = c("1", "2"),
                     labels = c("A", "B"))
ovarian$resid.ds <- factor(ovarian$resid.ds,
                           levels = c("1", "2"),
                           labels = c("no", "yes"))
ovarian$ecog.ps <- factor(ovarian$ecog.ps,
                          levels = c("1", "2"),
                          labels = c("good", "bad"))

fit.coxph <- coxph(surv_object ~ rx + resid.ds + age_group + ecog.ps, 
                   data = ovarian)
 
survminer::ggforest(fit.coxph)
```

resulting plot:
[image]
I would like to have only one reference for the entire work: the rx

Do I need to use `rms::contrast`? How would you use it in that case?